# How can insert first value with maxID+1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert value in db with "max+1" and also set first value in query.

I use this query to increment:

```
Select max(ID)+1 TableName;
```

Now, Where can i insert default value. Default value insert as first entry. Then increment by 1.

Comment: Use `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`. Don't try to insert `ID+1`, this will cause race conditions and create duplicates.

Comment: @Fabio that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the starting value of an auto-incrementing column, you can turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` on and off again. When `IDENTITY_INSERT` is on, you can insert whatever value you like into the auto-increment column, but when it is off, the default, "MAX + 1" value is used. So you could do something like this to achieve what you want (I have used and then dropped a temp table but, you would use your own target table).

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTab
( 
  -- this is the identity column, which by default will start at 1 and will
  -- hold a new "max + 1" value each time you insert a row into the table.
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 ,AnotherColumn VARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @FirstId INT = 50;
DECLARE @Value  VARCHAR(255) = 'Foo'

-- Let's insert a first value to show the override for the identity column, using your @FirstId value
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MyTab) = 0
BEGIN
    -- This is the bit that allows you to start the IDENTITY column at your value
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTab ON;

    INSERT #MyTab   (Id,AnotherColumn)
    VALUES          (@FirstId,@Value);

    -- This resets the IDENTITY column to produce default values in subsequent inserts
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTab OFF;
END
ELSE
    INSERT #MyTab   (AnotherColumn)
    VALUES          (@Value);

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Let's insert a second value to show the default behaviour
SET @Value = 'Bar'

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #MyTab) = 0
BEGIN
    -- This is the bit that allows you to start the IDENTITY column at your value
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTab ON;

    INSERT #MyTab   (Id,AnotherColumn)
    VALUES          (@FirstId,@Value);

    -- This resets the IDENTITY column to produce default values in subsequent inserts
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #MyTab OFF;
END
ELSE
    INSERT #MyTab   (AnotherColumn)
    VALUES          (@Value);

-- display the results
SELECT * FROM #MyTab;

-- clean up
DROP TABLE #MyTab;
```

of course if you know what the starting value is going to be, you can just declare the identity column using that value `Id INT IDENTITY(x,1) NOT NULL` where x is your first value.

Answer (score 0):

use IDENTITY.

```
IDENTITY [(seed, increment)]
```

> Seed: Starting value of a column. 
>         Default value is 1.
>
> Increment: Incremental value that is 
>   added to the identity value of the previous 
>   row that was loaded. The default value 1.

example:

```
create table employee 
( 
  ID IDENTITY(1,1), 
  name varchar(50)
)
```

It will start the ID by 1 and will increment the value by 1 on each insert.